# I sent Solana to an SPL token account on accident not realizing it can’t pay the fee to transfer it back - how to u retrieve? I have private key

Tags: spl-token, spl-associated-token-account

How do i do this? Do i need to write a program? Is there an existing repo than can be cloned and run? I have tried using CLI in a terminal but haven’t had any luck.

Answer (score 1):

To recover the SOL you need to close the token account.

You will have to send all its tokens out to another token account, as only empty accounts can be closed.

To close a specific token account you have several options:

- solana cli: `spl-token close <TOKEN_ADDRESS>`
- in wallet: solflare supports it, looks like phantom does not
- uis:

https://www.draffle.io/tools/close-token-accounts

https://sol-incinerator.com/#/

...